# Как удалить из строки весь текст до заданной подстроки?

Tags: java, строки, парсер

Конечно, глупый вопрос, но все же. Никак не могу разобраться.
Есть строка:

```
String s = "бла бла-бла сывSU";
```

Так вот вопрос, как отделить в java "бла бла-бла сыв" от SU?
Перед "SU" может быть любой текст символы и так далее. "SU" является главным идентификатором.

Заранее спасибо.

И ещё раз извините за глупые вопросы.

Comment: `String bla="бла бла-бла сыв"; String su= "SU";` Для более общего ответа нужно определить формально чем эти строки друг от друга отличаются

Comment: substring()
Позволяет получить часть содержимого. Есть две формы метода. В первом случае нужно указать индекс начала позиции, с которой нужно получить подстроку. Во втором варианте указывается начальный индекс и конечный индекс, если нужно получить текст из середины строки. Естественно ты ещё должен определить позиции SU

Comment: @Kleimosc нужно получить все что после "SU" включительно. Какой индекс мне необходимо указать в этом случае? Спасибо.

Comment: @defaultlocale возможно я не конретизировал задачу. Формально перед "SU" может быть что угодно, от этого нужно избавиться. Вопрос, каким образом!? Спасибо.

Comment: Если всё что после то используй так String s=  str.substring(str.lastIndexOf( "SU" );

Comment: @AntonKomyshan , ну как бы сплоховал, извиняйте :) Буду исправляться:)

Comment: @Kleimosc, спасибо, понял.

Comment: Точнее вот как будет выглядить это костыль. String s = "бла бла-бла сывSUdsdsdsds";
    System.out.print(s.substring(s.indexOf("SU")+2)); на выходе будет "dsdsdsds"

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, пока одни неясности. В строке обязательно будет "SU"? Нужно убрать все что перед "SU"? "SU" это буквально строка "SU" или это может быть "RU", "BLU", "BaRaBu"?

Comment: @Kleimosc спасибо, это действительно помогло

Comment: @defaultlocale по моему все понятно. Нужно убрать все что перед SU, это значит что только SU там может быть, а перед этим может все что угодно. Может не понятно описал, что перед SU может все что угодно. Ответ был получен.

Comment: @defaultlocale по Вашей рекомендации поменял внес изменения в вопрос.

Comment: @Philipesko стало лучше +1

Answer (score -1):

@Kleimosc ответил на вопрос. Правильным решением было:

```
String s= str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("SU");
```

После данной операции остается все что после SU включая SU.